# Formhandler error message is not translated

Tags: typo3, typoscript, html-formhandler

I'm using the Typo3 Formhandler extension to build a simple reaction form. The form works correctly only the error response is in English and not translated. By typoscript I included a languest file.

```
langFile = fileadmin/templates/sandraverdijck/lang/newsletter.xml
```

The languest file includes the Dutch translation, see file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3locallang>
 <data type="array">
  <languageKey index="default" type="array">

   <label index="error_sender_name_required">Naam is verplicht</label>

   <label index="error_sender_email_required">Email is verplicht</label>
   <label index="error_sender_email_email">Email is niet correct ingevult</label>
  </languageKey>
 </data>
</T3locallang>
```

The response is still in English like "Your name is missing", I don't know where it gets this from and why it is not using the text from the languest file? When I don't include the languest file I get an error so the file is used. Anyone some idee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your language key is default. Is Dutch the default language of the website? Are you setting the language through

```
config.language = dk
```

? If so, try using the according language code in the XML file:

```
<languageKey index="dk" type="array">
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed changing index="default" to index="nl" fixed the problem.